# I'm trying to exclude momentjs from the project as much as possible, but this does not give results

Tags: reactjs, webpack, momentjs, next.js, bundle

On a large project (Reactjs / Nextjs) momentjs was used.
I first excluded it completely from client pages, then from the project as a whole, but it has not disappeared anywhere and is displayed in the bandle of pages.
Is also present in node_modules (apparently some other library uses it as a dependency).

[image]

How to remove momentjs from the bundle of the page where it is not even used?
Please tell me the correct way to optimize the bundle size. (I have already removed the locale).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If it is in the bundle that there is someone consuming it, find the user of the lib, and decide what to do with it, you can run `npm why momentjs` to see the dependency tree

Comment: I dont understand, why in my any page bundle I see momentjs(I have not page without it).

I'm ready to leave momentjs, I just wanted to remove it where it is not used directly or as part of another module.

Comment: Did you tried to run `npm why ...`? what lib uses it?

Comment: Sorry, command not works for me. (I'm not in development for so long)

Comment: But I still have an assumption, since I am using Nextjs, then in _app or in _document something calls moment (redux-saga, or when it refers to the route or server model) and this can propagate moment to all pages, or I'm wrong ?

Comment: It is not true, in Next.js each page is an entry point of webpack (_app as well), therefore, if you have a lib inside a page bundle this means that you page consumes it directly or in-directly.

Comment: Regarding the command, it is `npm ls momentjs` (it is `yarn why momentjs` if you are using yarn)

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching us how to conduct an audit. I determined which libraries additionally pull momentjs (in my case, these are chart, js and react-day-picker). On the other hand, I still don't understand why moment is present absolutely everywhere on bundles / client.html, because not all pages use the above libraries.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time and my english